# Work manager android: UI is blocking while writing the file to local storage

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

This is my worker class:

```
 class CoroutineDownloadJSONWorker(val context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
        CoroutineWorker(context, params) {
        private var notificationManager: NotificationManager? = null

        companion object {
            private const val WORK_NAME = "CoroutineDownloadJSONWorker"
            const val PARAM_PROGRESS = "Progress"

            fun run(context: Context): LiveData<WorkInfo> {
                val work = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<CoroutineDownloadJSONWorker>()
                    .build()

                val manager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                manager.enqueueUniqueWork(WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, work)
                return manager.getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(work.id)
            }

            fun stop(context: Context) {
                //  Timber.d("stop")
                val manager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
                manager.cancelUniqueWork(WORK_NAME)
            }
        }

        override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
            notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            val progress = "Starting Download"
            setForegroundAsync(createForegroundInfo(progress))
            val service = Api.getClient.create(ApiService::class.java)
            val call = service.getMapList().execute()
            if (call.isSuccessful) {
                val mapListResponse = call.body()
                if (!mapListResponse!!.result.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                    val fileUrl = mapListResponse.result!![mapListResponse.result.size - 1].id
                    // getDownloadUrl(fileUrl!!)
                    val mapUrls = service.getDownloadMapURL(fileUrl!!).execute()
                    if (mapUrls.isSuccessful) {
                        val mapUrlsResponse = mapUrls.body()
                        if (!mapUrlsResponse!!.json_link.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                            val fileUrl = mapUrlsResponse.json_link
                            val map = service.downloadLatestMap(fileUrl)!!.execute()
                            if (map.isSuccessful) {
                                if (map.body() != null) {
                                  //  getMapFromUrl(map.body())
                                    try {
                                        val futureStudioIconFile =
                                            File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "euthopia.json")
                                        var inputStream: InputStream? = null;
                                        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null;
                                        try {
                                            val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
                                            var fileSizeDownloaded:Long = 0;
                                            inputStream = (map.body()!!.byteStream())
                                            outputStream = FileOutputStream(futureStudioIconFile);
                                            while (true) {
                                                val read = inputStream.read(buffer);
                                                if (read == -1) {
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                                fileSizeDownloaded += read
                                                setForeground(createForegroundInfo(AppUtils.getBytesString(fileSizeDownloaded)))

                                            }
                                            outputStream.flush();
                                            saveToDB()
                                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                                        } finally {
                                            if (inputStream != null) {
                                                inputStream.close();
                                            }
                                            if (outputStream != null) {
                                                outputStream.close();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                        }

                    }
                }

            }


            return Result.success()
        }


        private fun createForegroundInfo(progress: String): ForegroundInfo {
            val context = context
            val id = context.getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
            val title = context.getString(R.string.notification_title)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            }
            val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, id)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setTicker(title)
                .setContentText(progress)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setOngoing(true) // Add the cancel action to the notification which can
              .build()
            return ForegroundInfo(notification)
        }

    }
```

I am following this tutorial [work manager codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/#0). I am trying to download the JSON file from the server and saving it into local storage. I am not sure why the UI is blocking. while writing the file into local storage in  `doWork()` function of `CoroutineWorker`. I am showing the progress on a notification while writing the file. The app getting stuck.

Comment: can you upload a sample project to Github and share it?

Answer (score 0):

This code looks fine, I believe your problem isn't here, you can see on which thread you run the `doWork` function using this line `Thread.currentThread().name` (print it using a log), but I believe it won't be main thread. so you might blocking the main thread waiting for the result, but we will need more code in order to know that.

Did you consider using RXJava/Kotlin here? I think it will be simpler in that case.

Comment: It would be good if I resolve the issue with the current approach > work manager with coroutine.

Comment: So as I said, I think the problem isn't here, but you should check on which thread you copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `CoroutineWorker`, in your `doWork()` you should run all the codes in `Dispatchers.IO` coroutine scope like this:

```
class CoroutineDownloadWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

    override val coroutineContext = Dispatchers.IO

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result = coroutineScope {
        val jobs = (0 until 100).map {
            async {
                downloadSynchronously("https://www.google.com")
            }
        }

        // awaitAll will throw an exception if a download fails, which CoroutineWorker will treat as a failure
        jobs.awaitAll()
        Result.success()
    }
}
```

The example is taken from: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/coroutineworker